# Docker not receiving requests over host network

Tags: docker

On MacOS Big Sur or Ubuntu Desktop, when I run **any** docker on the host network, I cannot send an http request into the container.

Example docker that has an application running on localhost:4444

```
docker pull selenium/standalone-chrome
docker run -d --name grid_container_host --network host selenium/standalone-chrome

curl localhost:4444 #DOES NOT WORK
```

How can I receive http requests on a docker on the host network?

Things I have tried:

I tried running dockers on a new custom network, and publish the ports, then the docker receives the http request. However, this way, I cannot send an outgoing http request FROM the docker.

Also, if another docker is on the `--network host` it can receive http requests from dockers on `--network host`. But cannot receive a request from the Mac into the docker.

Comment: [Host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) "is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac".  It's usually unnecessary even on native Linux, where it does work.  Do you need a `-p 4444:4444` option to publish a port, and to remove the `--network host` option?

Comment: @DavidMaze ahh -- the weird thing is I can only get an outgoing request from the pre loaded app on this docker if it is a host mode. I have tried it with the `-p 4444:4444` option, I can get a request in this way, I can get a curl request going out. However, the java app running cannot get an API call out to `localhost` or `host.docker.internal` Any idea on that?

Comment: Requests from inside a container use the container's DNS first and the host, this means if you expose a port like `docker run -ti --rm -p 4444:4444 containerA` and a second containerB you needer refer to them explicitly. inside containerB if you run `curl localhost:4444` it's the same is if you were to run `curl containerB:4444` and not "local" to the host. Does that make sense?

Comment: Perhaps you can add `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` to your command. I use this as `extra_hosts` on my docker compose yml, and can successfully network with the host, without a `--network host` option. Useful when you run services like Postfix or bind9 on the host.

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions, but the only way the java app running on the docker can send a proper API request is by using `--network host` (I can get curl to send outgoing requests)  However, when I use the `--network host` I cannot get an API into the docker. Running docker inspect shows that there is no IP assigned. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: I actually put this onto an Ubuntu Desktop and still have the same issue, running any server app on `--network host` does not receive incoming api requests from the host

Comment: Forget about `--network host`, you should focus on figuring out why you can't connect to the internet from the container using bridge (default) network and simply published ports, as others recommended here. Paste the details of `docker network ls` and `docker network inspect` on your question please. You should be able to access the host from containers, using the `host.docker.internal` hostname from my previous comment. Right ?

Comment: @Niloct I got it working by changing some of the Java code which is irrelevant to most SO users and using the `--add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway` flag. You want to make an answer with this flag, and I will accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `--network host` except for most basic local testing environments. Even for a development setup, it's useful to put the same network settings you deploy on production.

In case of docker composed services, I use to do like this on `docker-compose.yml`:

```
networks:
  server_net:
    driver: bridge
    name: my-domain
    ipam:
     config:
       - subnet: 192.168.200.0/24
         gateway: 192.168.200.1
```

And for each service, `nginx`, for instance:

```
dns:
  - 172.17.0.1
extra_hosts:
  - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
container_name: nginx-server
networks:
  server_net:
    ipv4_address: 192.168.200.2
```

---

Notice that this setup is using the DNS server on the host (i.e. the `dns` key is set to `172.17.0.1`, so the containers will lookup DNS by default in the host).

Nevertheless, docker's internal DNS resolution will always prevail for resolution of `container-name`.`network-name` to container IP **and** the reverse IP address resolution too.

That is so important, when you realize that even running `bind9` on the host with correctly setup zones, the internal docker **reverse IP** address resolution (i.e. the one which resolves from `192.168.200.2` to `nginx-server`.`my-domain` on my example) still will *always* prevail over a local host DNS with this same information. This drove me mad for a bit, because my `container_name` was `nginx_service` (with an underscore) and my zone address host was `nginx-service`, so reverse lookup for the IP always yielded `nginx_service`, and this broke my postfix instance.

Considering this, the reason a host local DNS is still useful, besides local domain resolution, is for making a recursive server which can enforce `DNSSEC` requests for internet services. That's the rationale behind this setup.